# Get order of JQuery sortable divs with ID's

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I currently have a set of divs as follows:

```
  <ol id ="listOfApplied">
    <div id ="modalBody">
        <li id ="1"><div class='myDiv' id ="id1"><h4>Item 1</h4>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id ="2"><div class='myDiv' id ="id2"><h4>Item 2</h4>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id ="3"><div class='myDiv' id ="id3"><h4>Item 3</h4>
        </div>
        </li>

    </div>
  </ol>
```

Currently this is being displayed in a modal window and when I click the save button I want to get the order of the list, but what I need is the li id ( in order to know its position) and the div id to know what the li is referencing. Right now what I have is:

```
$("#listModalBody").on("click","#saveOrder", function(){


            $("#listOfApplied").sortable({
          });
          var listElements =  $("#listOfApplied").sortable("toArray") ;
           console.log(listElements);


    });
```

But that just returns a massive complicated array with many fields in it. Is there a way to just get the information I need? Thanks in advance!

Update- my save function:

```
  $(function() {
  $("#listModalBody").on("click","#saveOrder", function(){


      var ordered_divs= [];
      $("#listOfApplied li").sort(function (a, b) {
          return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
      }).each(function () {
          console.log($(this).text());
          ordered_divs.push({li_id: $(this).prop('id'), div_id: $(this).find('div').prop('id')});
      });
      console.log(ordered_divs);

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ordered_divs= [];
 var positions;

  $( "#listOfApplied").sortable({
       update: function(event, ui) {
              $('#listOfApplied li').each( function(e) {
                  console.log({li_id: $(this).prop('id'), div_id: $(this).find('div').prop('id')});
                  ordered_divs.push({li_id: $(this).prop('id'), div_id: $(this).find('div').prop('id')});
               });
              positions = ordered_divs.join(';')
             }
  });

$('#GetOrder').on('click',function(){
  console.dir(positions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id ="listOfApplied">
        <li id ="1"><div class='myDiv' id ="id1"><h4>Item 1</h4>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id ="2"><div class='myDiv' id ="id2"><h4>Item 2</h4>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li id ="3"><div class='myDiv' id ="id3"><h4>Item 3</h4>
        </div>
        </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="GetOrder">Get Order</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question, I'm looking to get an array which returns the order of the divs. In the array I ideally need something like data [ 'li_id' :1, 'div id': 2], [ 'li_id' :2, 'div id': 3] [ 'li_id' :3, 'div id': 1] .. which would be if item 2 was first in the list, item 3 was second and item 1 was third.. I appreciate your help though! :)

Comment: Example modified to create your array.

Comment: thats exactly what I'm looking for with the return! just one thing, when I click the save button, The object returned to me still shows the original order, even after I have moved the divs, is there something I'm doing wrong? Ive updated my question. The code you have above is exactly the kind of data I'm looking to return though! Thanks

Comment: Are you updating the IDs while you are moving the divs? double check that the IDs are being updated in the way you need it. By dragging and dropping elements won't do it by itself.

Comment: From the silence I've got :) I've modified the example to meet what you need with a sortable, how about now?

Comment: for some reason it is telling me "disableSelection is not a function".. is this deprecated? I really appreciate all of your help! :)

Comment: Is not really needed, it is more of a way I've got used to it every time I created a sortable. It has been deprecated, yes. Once you get your correct implementation you can vote the answer if it really helped!

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! :) I'll accept the answer right now, thanks again!